# $\zeta(1)=\frac12\ln(2)$? Did I do something wrong?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

I attempted to calculate $\zeta(1)$ and I got $\frac12\ln(2)$.

\begin{align}\zeta(1)&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{\zeta(1+\epsilon)+\zeta(1-\epsilon)}2\\&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{\frac1{1-2^{-\epsilon}}\eta(1+\epsilon)+\frac1{1-2^\epsilon}\eta(1-\epsilon)}2\\&=\frac12\eta(1)\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac1{1-2^{-\epsilon}}+\frac1{1-2^\epsilon}\\&=\frac12\eta(1)\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{2-2^\epsilon-2^{-\epsilon}}{(1-2^{-\epsilon})(1-2^\epsilon)}\\&=\frac12\eta(1)\lim_{\epsilon\to0}1\\&=\frac12\ln(2)\end{align}

Usually, one has $\zeta(1)=\pm\infty,\gamma,$ or $\ln(2)$ as a possible result that replaces $\gamma$, but I've never seen someone get $\zeta(1)=\frac12\ln(2)$.  Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: The main mistake is that one cannot "extract" $\eta(1\pm\epsilon)$ like that, to replace them both by $\eta(1)$ (in line 3).

Comment: @Did Ah, ok.  That makes some sense.  Is it possible to still evaluate the limit?

Comment: What, the limit of $\zeta(s)$ when $s\to1$? Yes, this is possible...

Comment: if $F(s)$ is meromorphic and has a simple pole at $s = 1$, i.e. $F(s) = \frac{a}{s-1} + G(s)$ with $G(s)$ holomorphic (analytic) at $s=1$, then $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} F(1+\epsilon) +F(1-\epsilon) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{a}{1+\epsilon-1}+\frac{a}{1-\epsilon-1} + G(1+\epsilon) +G(1-\epsilon) = 2 G(1)$$ hence with $F(s) = \zeta(s)$ you get $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \zeta(1+\epsilon) +\zeta(1-\epsilon) = 2 \gamma$$ with $\gamma$ the Euler constant, and this has nothing to do with $\zeta(1)$ (which doesn't exist) or with $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \zeta(1+\epsilon) = +\infty$

Comment: also note that $a$ is called the residue of $F(s)$ at $s=1$ : $$a = \lim_{s\to 1} F(s) (s-1)$$ (again when $F(s)$ is meromorphic and has a simple pole at $s=1$)

Comment: @user1952009 Thanks for the thoughts.  Is there a particular name for the area of math that deals with what you said?  I'd like to know more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

$$\frac{1}{1-2^{-\epsilon}} = \frac{1}{1-\exp(-\epsilon\log 2)} = \frac{1}{\epsilon\log 2 + O(\epsilon^2)}$$

and similarly for $\frac{1}{1-2^{\epsilon}}$, the small difference between $\eta(1)$ and $\eta(1\pm \epsilon)$ matters. If we use a first order Taylor expansion of $\eta$ at $1$, namely $\eta(1\pm \epsilon) = \eta(1) \pm \epsilon \eta'(1) + O(\epsilon^2)$, we find

\begin{align}
\frac{\zeta(1+\epsilon) + \zeta(1-\epsilon)}{2} &= \frac{1}{2}\biggl(\frac{\eta(1) + \epsilon \eta'(1) + O(\epsilon^2)}{1-2^{-\epsilon}} + \frac{\eta(1) -\epsilon\eta'(1) + O(\epsilon^2)}{1-2^{\epsilon}}\biggr) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\Biggl(\eta(1)\biggl(\frac{2^{\epsilon}}{2^{\epsilon}-1} + \frac{1}{1-2^{\epsilon}}\biggr) + \\
&\qquad\quad\eta'(1)\biggl(\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon\log 2 + O(\epsilon^2)} + \frac{-\epsilon}{-\epsilon\log 2 + O(\epsilon^2)}\biggr) + O(\epsilon)\Biggr) \\
&= \frac{\eta(1)}{2} + \frac{\eta'(1)}{\log 2} + O(\epsilon)
\end{align}

and therefore

$$\gamma = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{\zeta(1+\epsilon) + \zeta(1-\epsilon)}{2} = \frac{\log 2}{2} + \frac{\eta'(1)}{\log 2}.$$

Comment: Finally something I can accept :D